# Import XML into Google Sheets

Tags: xml, google-sheets, web-scraping, xpath, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to import some data from a website which are updated monthly in google sheets. I am particularly interested in this number: "1910" [see this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gw54V.jpg).

I typed:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://ratings.fide.com/card.phtml?event=36050601";"//table[@class='contentpaneopen']/tr[2]//tr[1]//tr[4]//tr[1]/td[1]")
```

My problem is that it imports both `std.` and then `1910`, because they are in the same cell. 
Is it possible to get rid of this `std.` and import only the value `1910`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use index to get the third returned value like this:

```
=index(IMPORTXML("https://ratings.fide.com/card.phtml?event=36050601","//table[@class='contentpaneopen']/tr[2]//tr[1]//tr[4]//tr[1]/td[1]"),0,3)
```